# Source shell script and access exported variables from os.environ

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a shell script where certain parameters are being set like:
**k.sh:**

```
export var="value"
export val2="value2"
```

Then I have a python script where i am calling the shell script and want to use these enviornment variables
**ex1.py:**

```
import subprocess
import os
subprocess.call("source k.sh",shell=True)
print os.environ["var"]
```

But I am getting a `KeyError`
How can I use these shell variables in my Python script?

Comment: Does it work with `os.system` instead of `subprocess.call`?

Comment: @SethMMorton:No,it doesnt work with os.system

Comment: This is not a good idea.  The question is why are you trying to do this.  What are you really wanting to do here? Just pass variables back to the parent?

Comment: @cmd :I have many directory structure path set as shell variables in different shell scripts,and i need to use these shell variables in my python script

Comment: @ftw do they need to be environment variables?  can you pass these values to the parent and have him set his own environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.call` starts a shell in a new process, which calls `source`. There is no way to modify the environment within your process from a child process.

Comment: This is not entirely helpful. I bet you could get at the environment of the subprocess.

Comment: @Marcin it's either going to require help from the child process (e.g. by it printing its environment and reading it back from the parent process), or something much more involved. Far from trivial, and it's *certainly* not going to work through `os.environ` in the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You could source `k.sh` *and* run a Python one-liner to print the contents of `os.environ` as JSON. Then use `json.loads` to convert that output back into a dict in your main process:

```
import subprocess
import os
import json
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
output = subprocess.check_output(
    ". ~/tmp/k.sh && python -c 'import os, json; print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))'",
    shell=True)
env = json.loads(output)
print(env["var"])
```

yields

```
value
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the environment and then run a Python script, well, set the environment and run the Python script using **runner**:

**runner**:

```
#! /bin/bash
. k.sh
exec ex1.py
```

and that's it.

**ex1.py**:

```
#import subprocess
import os
#subprocess.call("source k.sh",shell=True)
print os.environ["var"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by chepner. You'r subprocess part is runnign individually.
Working with environment variables has to be done prior to launching the python script..

For instance:

```
C:\Users\anton\Desktop\githubs>echo %x%
y

C:\Users\anton\Desktop\githubs>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['x']
'y'
>>>
```

Sourcing your environment variables prior to launching the script will traverse down however, or if you execute multiple commands to the subprocess call that would also be great after you sourced it. for instance:

```
import subprocess
import os
x = subprocess.call("source k.sh",shell=True, STDIN=subprocess.PIPE, STDOUT=subprocess.PIPE)
y = subprocess.call("echo $var",shell=True, STDIN=x.stdout, STDOUT=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Never tried that tho, as mentioned. Source it before launch.

Answer (score 0):

/u/unutbu already answered this question. However I fixed couple of bugs in his code:

```
def run_external_script(script):
    if is_windows():
        command = script+" && python -c \"import os; print dict(os.environ)\""
    else:
        command = ". "+ script+" && python -c 'import os; print dict(os.environ)'"

    output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).communicate()[0]
    r = re.compile('{.*}')
    m = r.search(output)
    try:
        env = eval(m.group(0))
    except:
        error( "Something went wrong in " + script )
        error( output )
    return env
```

There are couple of small differences:

- This code works both on windows/linux
- I replaced subprocess.check_output with subprocess.call, check_output requires Python 2.7
- When I ran his code, there std out of the script would also got printed in the output variables. So I used a re to grab the dictionary everything between two {}, such as {'var1'=1, 'var2'='x'}.
- instead of using json, I used python's eval. There is a chance of injection, so use it at your own risk. such as `{; exit(1); }`

Answer (score 0):

If your on windows you could set an environment variable with powershell

```
os.system("powershell.exe [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('key', 'value','User')")
```

its worth noting before your application can use the variables you will need to restart you application to allow it to read the updated variables...

then you can access with

```
yourValue = os.environ['key']
```